# Ruby - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to query another table in a model definition.

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "miq_user_roles" LINE 1: ..." = $1 AND "service_templates"."display" = $2 AND "miq_user_... ^ [catalog/explorer]
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

```
  scope :with_service_template_catalog_id,          ->(cat_id) { where(:service_template_catalog_id => cat_id) }
  scope :without_service_template_catalog_id,       ->         { where(:service_template_catalog_id => nil) }
  scope :with_existent_service_template_catalog_id, ->         { where.not(:service_template_catalog_id => nil) }
  scope :displayed,                                 ->         { where(:display => true) }
  scope :public_service_templates,                  ->         { where("miq_user_roles.settings" => nil) }
```

Here is the full code:

```
class ServiceTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  include SupportsFeatureMixin

  DEFAULT_PROCESS_DELAY_BETWEEN_GROUPS = 120

  GENERIC_ITEM_SUBTYPES = {
    "custom"          => N_("Custom"),
    "vm"              => N_("Virtual Machine"),
    "playbook"        => N_("Playbook"),
    "hosted_database" => N_("Hosted Database"),
    "load_balancer"   => N_("Load Balancer"),
    "storage"         => N_("Storage")
  }.freeze

  SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC    = 'atomic'.freeze
  SERVICE_TYPE_COMPOSITE = 'composite'.freeze

  RESOURCE_ACTION_UPDATE_ATTRS = [:dialog,
                                  :dialog_id,
                                  :fqname,
                                  :configuration_template,
                                  :configuration_template_id,
                                  :configuration_template_type].freeze

  include CustomActionsMixin
  include ServiceMixin
  include OwnershipMixin
  include NewWithTypeStiMixin
  include TenancyMixin
  include ArchivedMixin
  include CiFeatureMixin
  include_concern 'Filter'
  include_concern 'Copy'

  validates :name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :tenant

  has_many   :service_templates, :through => :service_resources, :source => :resource, :source_type => 'ServiceTemplate'
  has_many   :services

  has_many :service_template_tenants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :additional_tenants, :through => :service_template_tenants, :source => :tenant, :dependent => :destroy

  has_one :picture, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :resource, :autosave => true

  belongs_to :service_template_catalog
  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :currency, :inverse_of => false

  has_many   :dialogs, -> { distinct }, :through => :resource_actions
  has_many   :miq_schedules, :as => :resource, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many   :miq_requests, :as => :source, :dependent => :nullify
  has_many   :active_requests, -> { where(:request_state => MiqRequest::ACTIVE_STATES) }, :as => :source, :class_name => "MiqRequest"

  virtual_column   :type_display,                 :type => :string
  virtual_column   :template_valid,               :type => :boolean
  virtual_column   :template_valid_error_message, :type => :string
  virtual_column   :archived,                     :type => :boolean
  virtual_column   :active,                       :type => :boolean

  default_value_for :internal, false
  default_value_for :service_type, SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC
  default_value_for(:generic_subtype) { |st| 'custom' if st.prov_type == 'generic' }

  virtual_has_one :config_info, :class_name => "Hash"


  scope :with_service_template_catalog_id,          ->(cat_id) { where(:service_template_catalog_id => cat_id) }
  scope :without_service_template_catalog_id,       ->         { where(:service_template_catalog_id => nil) }
  scope :with_existent_service_template_catalog_id, ->         { where.not(:service_template_catalog_id => nil) }
  scope :displayed,                                 ->         { where(:display => true) }
  scope :public_service_templates,                  ->         { where("miq_user_roles.settings" => nil) }

 supports :order do
    unsupported_reason_add(:order, 'Service template does not belong to a service catalog') unless service_template_catalog
    unsupported_reason_add(:order, 'Service template is not configured to be displayed') unless display
  end
  alias orderable?     supports_order?
  alias validate_order supports_order?


  def self.with_tenant(tenant_id)
    tenant = Tenant.find(tenant_id)
    where(:tenant_id => tenant.ancestor_ids + [tenant_id])
  end

  def self.with_additional_tenants
    references(table_name, :tenants).includes(:service_template_tenants => :tenant)
  end

  def self.all_catalog_item_types
    @all_catalog_item_types ||= begin
      builtin_catalog_item_types = {
        "generic"               => N_("Generic"),
        "generic_orchestration" => N_("Orchestration"),
      }

      ExtManagementSystem.subclasses_supporting(:catalog)
        .flat_map(&:catalog_types)
        .reduce(builtin_catalog_item_types, :merge)
    end
  end

  def self.catalog_item_types
    ems_classes = Rbac.filtered(ExtManagementSystem.all).collect(&:class).uniq.select { |ems| ems.supports?(:catalog) }
    ci_types = Set.new(ems_classes.flat_map(&:catalog_types).reduce({}, :merge).keys)

    ci_types.add('generic_orchestration') if Rbac.filtered(OrchestrationTemplate).exists?
    ci_types.add('generic')

    all_catalog_item_types.each.with_object({}) do |(key, description), hash|
      hash[key] = {:description => description, :display => ci_types.include?(key)}
    end
  end

  def self.create_catalog_item(options, auth_user)
    transaction do
      create_from_options(options).tap do |service_template|
        config_info = options[:config_info].except(:provision, :retirement, :reconfigure)

        workflow_class = MiqProvisionWorkflow.class_for_source(config_info[:src_vm_id])
        if workflow_class
          request = workflow_class.new(config_info, auth_user).make_request(nil, config_info)
          service_template.add_resource(request)
        end
        service_template.create_resource_actions(options[:config_info])
      end
    end
  end

  def self.class_from_request_data(data)
    request_type = data['prov_type']
    if request_type.include?('generic_')
      generic_type = request_type.split('generic_').last
      "ServiceTemplate#{generic_type.camelize}".constantize
    else
      ServiceTemplate
    end
  end

  def update_catalog_item(options, auth_user = nil)
    config_info = validate_update_config_info(options)
    unless config_info
      update!(options)
      return reload
    end
    transaction do
      update_from_options(options)

      update_service_resources(config_info, auth_user)

      update_resource_actions(config_info)
      save!
    end
    reload
  end

  def children
    service_templates
  end

  def descendants
    children.flat_map { |child| [child] + child.descendants }
  end

  def subtree
    [self] + descendants
  end

  def vms_and_templates
    []
  end

  def destroy
    if parent_services.present?
      raise MiqException::MiqServiceError, _("Cannot delete a service that is the child of another service.")
    end

    service_resources.each do |sr|
      rsc = sr.resource
      rsc.destroy if rsc.kind_of?(MiqProvisionRequestTemplate)
    end
    super
  end

  def archive
    raise _("Cannot archive while in use") unless active_requests.empty?
    archive!
  end

  def retireable?
    false
  end

  def request_class
    ServiceTemplateProvisionRequest
  end

  def request_type
    "clone_to_service"
  end

  def config_info
    options[:config_info] || construct_config_info
  end

  def create_service(service_task, parent_svc = nil)
    nh = attributes.dup

    # Service#display was renamed to #visible in https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq-schema/pull/410
    nh['visible'] = nh.delete('display') if nh.key?('display')

    nh['options'][:dialog] = service_task.options[:dialog]
    (nh.keys - Service.column_names + %w(created_at guid service_template_id updated_at id type prov_type)).each { |key| nh.delete(key) }

    # Hide child services by default
    nh['visible'] = false if parent_svc

    # If visible is nil, set it to false
    nh['visible'] ||= false

    # convert template class name to service class name by naming convention
    nh['type'] = self.class.name.sub('Template', '')

    nh['initiator'] = service_task.options[:initiator] if service_task.options[:initiator]

    service = Service.create!(nh) do |svc|
      svc.service_template = self
      set_ownership(svc, service_task.get_user)

      service_resources.each do |sr|
        nh = sr.attributes.dup
        %w(id created_at updated_at service_template_id).each { |key| nh.delete(key) }
        svc.add_resource(sr.resource, nh) unless sr.resource.nil?
      end
    end

    service.tap do |svc|
      if parent_svc
        service_resource = ServiceResource.find_by(:id => service_task.options[:service_resource_id])
        parent_svc.add_resource!(svc, service_resource)
      end
    end
  end

  def composite?
    service_type.to_s.include?(self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_COMPOSITE)
  end

  def atomic?
    service_type.to_s.include?(self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC)
  end

  def type_display
    case service_type
    when self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC    then "Item"
    when self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_COMPOSITE then "Bundle"
    when nil                                then "Unknown"
    else
      service_type.to_s.capitalize
    end
  end

  def create_tasks_for_service(service_task, parent_svc)
    unless parent_svc
      return [] unless self.class.include_service_template?(service_task,
                                                            service_task.source_id,
                                                            parent_svc)
    end
    svc = create_service(service_task, parent_svc)

    service_task.destination = svc

    create_subtasks(service_task, svc)
  end

  # default implementation to create subtasks from service resources
  def create_subtasks(parent_service_task, parent_service)
    tasks = []
    service_resources.each do |child_svc_rsc|
      scaling_min = child_svc_rsc.scaling_min
      1.upto(scaling_min).each do |scaling_idx|
        nh = parent_service_task.attributes.dup
        %w(id created_on updated_on type state status message).each { |key| nh.delete(key) }
        nh['options'] = parent_service_task.options.dup
        nh['options'].delete(:child_tasks)
        # Initial Options[:dialog] to an empty hash so we do not pass down dialog values to child services tasks
        nh['options'][:dialog] = {}
        next if child_svc_rsc.resource_type == "ServiceTemplate" &&
                !self.class.include_service_template?(parent_service_task,
                                                      child_svc_rsc.resource.id,
                                                      parent_service)
        new_task = parent_service_task.class.new(nh)
        new_task.options.merge!(
          :src_id              => child_svc_rsc.resource.id,
          :scaling_idx         => scaling_idx,
          :scaling_min         => scaling_min,
          :service_resource_id => child_svc_rsc.id,
          :parent_service_id   => parent_service.id,
          :parent_task_id      => parent_service_task.id,
        )
        new_task.state  = 'pending'
        new_task.status = 'Ok'
        new_task.source = child_svc_rsc.resource
        new_task.save!
        new_task.after_request_task_create
        parent_service_task.miq_request.miq_request_tasks << new_task

        tasks << new_task
      end
    end
    tasks
  end

  def set_ownership(service, user)
    return if user.nil?
    service.evm_owner = user
    if user.current_group
      $log.info("Setting Service Owning User to Name=#{user.name}, ID=#{user.id}, Group to Name=#{user.current_group.name}, ID=#{user.current_group.id}")
      service.miq_group = user.current_group
    else
      $log.info("Setting Service Owning User to Name=#{user.name}, ID=#{user.id}")
    end
  end

  def self.default_provisioning_entry_point(service_type)
    if service_type == 'atomic'
      '/Service/Provisioning/StateMachines/ServiceProvision_Template/CatalogItemInitialization'
    else
      '/Service/Provisioning/StateMachines/ServiceProvision_Template/CatalogBundleInitialization'
    end
  end

  def self.default_retirement_entry_point
    '/Service/Retirement/StateMachines/ServiceRetirement/Default'
  end

  def self.default_reconfiguration_entry_point
    nil
  end

  def template_valid?
    validate_template[:valid]
  end
  alias template_valid template_valid?

  def template_valid_error_message
    validate_template[:message]
  end

  def validate_template
    missing_resources = service_resources.select { |sr| sr.resource.nil? }

    if missing_resources.present?
      missing_list = missing_resources.collect { |sr| "#{sr.resource_type}:#{sr.resource_id}" }.join(", ")
      return {:valid   => false,
              :message => "Missing Service Resource(s): #{missing_list}"}
    end

    service_resources.detect do |s|
      r = s.resource
      r.respond_to?(:template_valid?) && !r.template_valid?
    end.try(:resource).try(:validate_template) || {:valid => true, :message => nil}
  end

  def provision_action
    resource_actions.find_by(:action => "Provision")
  end

  def update_resource_actions(ae_endpoints)
    resource_action_list.each do |action|
      resource_params = ae_endpoints[action[:param_key]]
      resource_action = resource_actions.find_by(:action => action[:name])
      # If the action exists in updated parameters
      if resource_params
        # And the resource action exists on the template already, update it
        if resource_action
          resource_action.update!(resource_params.slice(*RESOURCE_ACTION_UPDATE_ATTRS))
        # If the resource action does not exist, create it
        else
          build_resource_action(resource_params, action)
        end
      elsif resource_action
        # If the endpoint does not exist in updated parameters, but exists on the template, delete it
        resource_action.destroy
      end
    end
  end

  def create_resource_actions(ae_endpoints)
    ae_endpoints ||= {}
    resource_action_list.each do |action|
      ae_endpoint = ae_endpoints[action[:param_key]]
      next unless ae_endpoint
      build_resource_action(ae_endpoint, action)
    end
    save!
  end

  def self.create_from_options(options)
    create!(options.except(:config_info).merge(:options => { :config_info => options[:config_info] }))
  end
  private_class_method :create_from_options

  def provision_request(user, options = nil, request_options = {})
    request_options[:provision_workflow] = true
    request_options[:parent_id] = options.delete('param_parent_request_id') unless options['param_parent_request_id'].nil?
    result = order(user, options, request_options)
    raise result[:errors].join(", ") if result[:errors].any?
    result[:request]
  end

  def picture=(value)
    if value.kind_of?(Hash)
      super(Picture.new(value))
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def queue_order(user_id, options, request_options)
    MiqQueue.submit_job(
      :class_name  => self.class.name,
      :instance_id => id,
      :method_name => "order",
      :args        => [user_id, options, request_options],
    )
  end

  def order(user_or_id, options = nil, request_options = {}, schedule_time = nil)
    user     = user_or_id.kind_of?(User) ? user_or_id : User.find(user_or_id)
    workflow = provision_workflow(user, options, request_options)
    if schedule_time
      require 'time'
      time = Time.parse(schedule_time).utc

      errors = workflow.validate_dialog
      errors << unsupported_reason(:order)
      return {:errors => errors} if errors.compact.present?

      schedule = MiqSchedule.create!(
        :name         => "Order #{self.class.name} #{id} at #{time}",
        :description  => "Order #{self.class.name} #{id} at #{time}",
        :sched_action => {:args => [user.id, options, request_options], :method => "queue_order"},
        :resource     => self,
        :run_at       => {
          :interval   => {:unit => "once"},
          :start_time => time,
          :tz         => "UTC",
        },
      )
      {:schedule => schedule}
    else
      workflow.submit_request
    end
  end

  def provision_workflow(user, dialog_options = nil, request_options = {})
    dialog_options ||= {}
    request_options.delete(:provision_workflow) if request_options[:submit_workflow]
    ra_options = request_options.slice(:initiator, :init_defaults, :provision_workflow, :submit_workflow).merge(:target => self)

    ResourceActionWorkflow.new(dialog_options, user, provision_action, ra_options).tap do |wf|
      wf.request_options = request_options
    end
  end

  def add_resource(rsc, options = {})
    super
    adjust_service_type
  end

  def self.display_name(number = 1)
    n_('Service Catalog Item', 'Service Catalog Items', number)
  end

  def my_zone
    # Catalog items can specify a zone to run in.
    # Catalog bundle are used for grouping catalog items and are therefore treated as zone-agnostic.
    zone&.name if atomic?
  end

  private

  def update_service_resources(config_info, auth_user = nil)
    config_info = config_info.except(:provision, :retirement, :reconfigure)
    workflow_class = MiqProvisionWorkflow.class_for_source(config_info[:src_vm_id])
    if workflow_class
      service_resources.find_by(:resource_type => 'MiqRequest').try(:destroy)
      new_request = workflow_class.new(config_info, auth_user).make_request(nil, config_info)

      add_resource!(new_request)
    end
  end

  def build_resource_action(ae_endpoint, action)
    fqname = ae_endpoint[:fqname] || self.class.send(action[:method], *action[:args]) || ""

    build_options = {:action        => action[:name],
                     :fqname        => fqname,
                     :ae_attributes => {:service_action => action[:name]}}
    build_options.merge!(ae_endpoint.slice(*RESOURCE_ACTION_UPDATE_ATTRS))
    resource_actions.build(build_options)
  end

  def validate_update_config_info(options)
    if options[:service_type] && options[:service_type] != service_type
      raise _('service_type cannot be changed')
    end
    if options[:prov_type] && options[:prov_type] != prov_type
      raise _('prov_type cannot be changed')
    end
    options[:config_info]
  end

  def resource_action_list
    [
      {:name      => ResourceAction::PROVISION,
       :param_key => :provision,
       :method    => 'default_provisioning_entry_point',
       :args      => [service_type]},
      {:name      => ResourceAction::RECONFIGURE,
       :param_key => :reconfigure,
       :method    => 'default_reconfiguration_entry_point',
       :args      => []},
      {:name      => ResourceAction::RETIREMENT,
       :param_key => :retirement,
       :method    => 'default_retirement_entry_point',
       :args      => []}
    ]
  end

  def update_from_options(params)
    options[:config_info] = params[:config_info]
    update!(params.except(:config_info))
  end

  def construct_config_info
    config_info = {}

    miq_request_resource = service_resources.find_by(:resource_type => 'MiqRequest')
    config_info.merge!(miq_request_resource.resource.options.compact) if miq_request_resource

    config_info.merge!(resource_actions_info)
  end

  def resource_actions_info
    resource_actions.each_with_object({}) do |resource_action, config_info|
      resource_options = resource_action.slice(:dialog_id, :configuration_template_type, :configuration_template_id).compact
      resource_options[:fqname] = resource_action.fqname
      config_info[resource_action.action.downcase.to_sym] = resource_options.symbolize_keys
    end
  end

  def generic_custom_buttons
    CustomButton.buttons_for("Service")
  end

  def adjust_service_type
    self.service_type = service_resources.any? { |st| st.resource_type.in?(['Service', 'ServiceTemplate']) } ? self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_COMPOSITE : self.class::SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scope :public_service_templates, -> {
  joins(:miq_user_roles).where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil }) 
}
```

Assuming the table exists. You need to join on that table in order to query it. Note, the default joins is an inner join that will remove records that don't have an associated `miq_user_roles`.

This will change the query substantially. If a record has_many `miq_user_roles` you'll likely need to add a distinct or distinct on clause. If it's possible to have no `miq_user_roles`, then records without them will now dissappear when you call the scope, since the inner join didn't find any.

Comment: I get the following error: 

Can't join 'ServiceTemplate' to association named 'miq_user_roles'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: You need to define the :miq_user_roles in your model, or from a mixin. Can you post more code showing where you do (or don't) define the association from?

Comment: Updated the code. Can you show me how to define? I wonder if just adding `has_many: :miq_user_roles ` would work?

Comment: `ServiceTemplate` has a column `miq_group_id` which is the `id` of `miq_user_roles`.

Comment: Is it the primary key of miq_user_roles? How does that work? Can you put the MiqGroup and MiqUserRole model? Or if they don't exist, add their schema?

It'll probably be something along the lines of ```has_many :miq_user_roles, foreign_key: :miq_group_id``` but I need to see.